# how to remove inclined lines added to legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to remove inclined lines added to legend? And also the dots on the yellow and gray... Why is it happening?

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
df = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2, v=2*x)
df2 = data.frame(x=x, y=x^2-5*x-10)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = v)) + 
  theme_classic() +   
  scale_size("blabla") +     
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x, y, color = "blue")) +
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x, y, color = "blue")) +
  geom_hline(aes(color="gray",yintercept=25)) +
  geom_abline(aes(color="yellow", intercept=0, slope=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","gray","yellow"), labels = c("nanana","hhh","abab"), name = "other")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the legend for the `color` aesthetic and it tries to combine all the needed information for `geom_point`, `geom_line`, `geom_hline`, and `geom_abline`. To get rid of the lines, we instead need

```
geom_abline(aes(color = "yellow", intercept = 0, slope = 1), show.legend = FALSE)
```

while for the dots we have to add

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(19, NA, NA))))
```

This gives

[image]